# 2 jquery accordions on one page, open panel in 2nd accordion from external link

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have Two Accordions on one page.  Currently, I am able to open up a specific panel in **Accordion 1** from an external link using mysite.htm?panel=0, mysite.htm?panel=1, mysite.htm?panel=2, etc.

However, I cannot figure out how to open up a specific panel in **Accordion 2** from an external page.

```
   <link href="../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.accordion.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="../jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui-1.10.4.accordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="Accordion1">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<p>&nbsp; </p>


<div id="Accordion2">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
      var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));
    $( "#Accordion1" ).accordion( 
    {active: defaultPanel}
    ); 

});

function getParam(name) {
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    if (query.length) {
        var parts = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var pos = parts[i].indexOf('=');
            if (parts[i].substring(0,pos) == name) {
                return parts[i].substring(pos+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
      var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));
    $( "#Accordion2" ).accordion( 
    {active: defaultPanel}
    ); 

});

function getParam(name) {
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    if (query.length) {
        var parts = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var pos = parts[i].indexOf('=');
            if (parts[i].substring(0,pos) == name) {
                return parts[i].substring(pos+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's a lot of code there. Could you please whittle it down to the [least amount necessary](/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem? That will help people give you good answers.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for responding!  I edited the code to be much more stripped down.  Let me know if I should add jquery asset codes too, though these should be the standard.  Much appreciated.

Comment: So, if you're already using `panel` to control the first accordion, couldn't you stick another parameter on the end to link to the other accordion? For example, `?panel=2&panel2=0`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It worked like a charm.  In the second accordion's javascript code I changed  **parseInt(getParam('panel'));**  to  **parseInt(getParam('panel2'));**.  Then in the url, to keep the first accordion panels closed but, for example, the second accordion's first panel open, I added to the end of the url **?panel=100&panel2=0**.  Thanks again, Andrew!